# How to send a Unity HoloLens 2 project for immediate testing by a remote colleague (without certification from Microsoft Store)

Tags: hololens, hololens-emulator

I am developing for HoloLens 2 and I don't have the device (I am using the Emulator to test).
I want to build the project with Unity and send the built package to a colleague that is not a developer - meaning, he is not good with Visual Studio - and who wants to test the app.

I tried using Microsoft Store and this worked for the initial P.O.C., but after the second submission I thought that it was going to be faster, but always takes up to 3 business days, which is not acceptable as a good workflow.

I know that, in ideal conditions, I should have the HoloLens, but this is not possible for now.

Do you have any idea on how to send packages to a non-developer person so that he can test the app in another country and so that it doesn't require a certification process like Microsoft Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the Sideloading feature provided by HoloLens Device Portal. Please follow this guide to connect the HoloLens over Wi-Fi or USB and manage your device from a web browser on your PC: [Installing an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-the-windows-device-portal#installing-an-app). In this way, you can directly send the app package to your colleague, and he can install it without using VS.

Comment: Thanks, Hernando!
This worked very well.
For others having this same problem, you need to, in Visual Studio, select "Publish -> Create App Package", choose "Sideloading" and then send a .zip file to the person that has the HoloLens.
After that, he needs to follow the guide mentioned by Hernando.